# Doing system backups by rotating the removal of a disk from a 3 disk RAID 1 system

Tags: hard-drive, backup, raid

Is it possible to create a system backup by creating a RAID 1 array of 3 disks with 1 of the disks always not connected to the system?

Overall Procedure:

1. Insert disks 1 & 2 into computer, hardware RAID 1, install OS.
2. Swap disk 3 in to replace disk 2.  Rebuild RAID 1 from disk 1 to 3

Now can we assume that disk 2 is a backup of the system?

3. Every week, repeat swap and RAID rebuild

When a roll back is needed can the external disk be inserted and the RAID array be rebuilt from it to the other disks?

Is this a recommended practice?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a system backup by creating a RAID 1 array
>   of 3 disks with 1 of the disks always not connected to the system?

Technically it is possible.

> Now can we assume that disk 2 is a backup of the system?

Yes. HW tends to make full disk arrays.
So you have a full copy of half a mirror.

> Every week, repeat swap and RAID rebuild.
>   Is this a recommended practice?

**NO!**

> Why or why not?

Several reasons. For starters you are making a full copy every week. If you have a 4TB disk and one file changed then you are still copying the full 4TB. **Wastefull*

Secondly you are assiming that the rebuilding always works, and you are testing that assumption weekly.  Not a practice I feel safe with. And if I needed to do that I would create a backup before trying this.  In your case, that kind of defeats the purpose.

Thirdly: Swapping hardware weekly will wear things out. Even hotswap connectors are not designed to be changed hundred of times.

Now, as what to are best practices:

- Multiple partitions, one with the OS, one with data.
- A good backup of the OS. This probably does not need weekly backups.
- A $longer_period full backup of all data and $shorter_period of incrementals. (or an rsync like backup).
- And an **off-site** location for the backups.

The last because having a backup is nice, but if you store it on-site and there is a fire you will also loose the backups. Ditto for lighting strikes. And doubly so when either happens during a backup cycle.

And if you do use off-site backups then the data reduction from incremental backups gets double interesting.

Also note that RAID is not backup. RAID is great to keep a server up and running when a disk fails. Than after office hours IT can do emergency maintenance. It is never a replacement for a backup.

And if used at home then you still want backups which are safe from fire, lightning, theft, ...